# Can I recover my /opt/local/bin folder that I accidentally deleted?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, data-recovery

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.8. I was recently uninstalling mysql5 from /opt/local/bin.

I typed:

```
rm -rf /opt/local/bin mysql*
```

instead of

```
rm -rf /opt/local/bin/mysql*
```

This deleted my entire /opt/local/bin directory which puts me in a bit of a bind.

Is there any way to recover those files?  If not, I have a friend that is using a similar set of programs, would it be possible to use the contents of his folder?

If I end up needing to reinstall everything in this folder, what is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: No backup? No.... `/opt/local/bin` is usually your macports directory so (unless you compiled stuff into there) a complete macports reinstall (including apps etc...) could do the trick. You'll of course lose everything you've done under macports. BTW: voting to migrate to superuser.com.

Comment: Welcome to UNIX. This is a rite of passage that every padawan must endure before being accepted into the brotherhood :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% fool-proof way to recover the files. In fact, if you've left the machine running after issuing the `rm` command, the OS might have mistakenly viewed the disk space formerly occupied by /opt/local/bin as free space, and may have written something there. Once that happens, complete recovery becomes pretty iffy.

Although there are data-recovery tools which one might use when such a disaster strikes, fortunately for you you lost programs, not personal data. The easiest, most sure-fire way to restore the directory is to reinstall the programs.

PS. Welcome to the club. It is usually only *after* such an experience that one becomes enthusiastic about backing up!

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled ports and all apps, etc.

I'm back up and running and getting a good backup strategy in place.

Comment: I recommend a cheap USB external drive and Time Machine for now